# Cannot download Planet data from SEPAL

Tags: planet, sepal

I'm using the planet-order module from SEPAL on the Maldives and I cannot manage to download my images. I get the following error:

> `downloads`

[image]

My API key seems legit and the mosaics have been loaded by the module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your API key is linked to a contract that doesn't have the right to download this mosaic in this specific place.

With a proper API key you should get :

[image]

Based on what I see on your screenshot, you do not have permission to download (with the API key entered) the mosaics available via SEPAL. The "global_monthly" mosaics available for download in SEPAL are from the NICFI / Planet data release.

The SEPAL tool is providing you a display interface to see the mosaics you're about to download and then download them to SEPAL, it doesn't pre-check if you can or cannot download the quads.

To obtain an API key enabling access to NICFI / Planet data, register at   https://www.planet.com/nicfi/

Full documentation on the use of the Planet download module in SEPAL is at https://docs.sepal.io/en/latest/modules/dwn/planet_order.html